# How to change SQL Server for JSON Auto column name?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

[image]
In this picture, result column name(JSON_F52...) is auto-generated by SQL Server. How to change this name to unique name?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Can use this code:

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [Order] FOR JSON AUTO) AS ColumnName
```

[image]